# Controlling SVG colors with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, sass

I'm setting up a few icons in a library that's using some basic CSS and an SVG Sprite (generated through webpack).

Some of the icons I want to be able to color with *multiple* colors. My set up looks like:

**mail.svg** *(details of the svg are omitted for simplicity)*

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="64" height="64">
  <polyline class="primary-stroke" fill="none" stroke-width="2" [more-stuff-here]></polyline>
  <path fill="none" stroke-width="2" [more-stuff-here]></path>
  <line class="primary-stroke" fill="none" stroke-width="2" [more-stuff-here]></line>
</svg>
```

My computed CSS (`blue` is the primary accent color) looks like:

```
svg {
  fill: currentColor;
  stroke: currentColor;
}

.primary-stroke {
  stroke: blue;
  fill: none;
}
```

And my HTML looks like:

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#mail"></svg>
```

This all works exactly as expected, but now I want to take it a step further. I want to be able to add a class to the element to determine if *this* instance should contain 1 single color or 2 colors.

My attempt was pretty simple. I just added a `single-color` class to the `svg` element to look like:

```
<svg class="single-color"><use xlink:href="#mail"></svg>
```

And modified the SCSS. The computed CSS looks like:

```
.single-color .primary-stroke {
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: none;
}
```

But, it definitely does not work. The `primary` styles still take effect. I'm new to working with SVGs and I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible with a sprite?

**CodePens demonstrating the issue:**

- Working Demo (no Sprites): https://codepen.io/amlyhamm/pen/ddjXBp
- Not Working (using Sprites): https://codepen.io/amlyhamm/pen/paZbMq

Both examples use the same classes and SVGs.

Comment: Are you sure that the new class is actually being applied?  I am just wondering if you are actually encountering a JS/DOM problem, and not a CSS problem...

Comment: The DOM itself shows that the `svg` element has the class. When selecting the actual `path` / `line` / `polyline` I cannot see styles from applied classes (I can't see the `primary-stroke` even in the working example). The computed styles (in Chrome's dev tools) shows the `blue` (as expected in the first instance, incorrect in the second). So, it's hard to tell?

Comment: I'll try to get a quick JSFiddle together to reference...

Comment: both of the rules have `!important` so the last one listed will be the one that takes over.

Comment: Just added a CodePen of the examples

Comment: Looks like `important` shouldn't even be necessary (see working CodePen that isn't using Sprites)

Comment: @Kaiido - yep, the whole shadow DOM thing makes sense. How would I go about targeting the `<use>` element and still get the two colors? Can you provide an example or an edit to the CodePen(s) in the question?

Comment: @amlyhamm added a simple example + an updated codepen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element referenced by the `<use>` element is not per se part of the DOM chain, it is only present in the shadow DOM, and hence, you can't access it through your selector.

The solution would be to target directly the `<use>` element itself, and don't set rules for the inner `.primary-stroke` so that they can inherit from the `<use>`.

```css
/* 
  don't set any direct rule on the .variable ones 
  otherwise, they won't be able to inherit from the <use>
*/

/* target the uses */
.stroke-only use[href="#rects"] {
  stroke: blue;
  fill: none;
}
.stroke-and-fill use[href="#rects"] {
  stroke: blue;
  fill: green;
}

/* this one won't get influenced by the <use> */
.fixed {
  fill: orange;
  stroke: red;
}

svg { display: block; }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1">
  <defs>
    <g id="rects">
      <rect class="variable" x=5 y=5 width=50 height=50 />
      <rect class="fixed" x=60 y=5 width=50 height=50 />
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="stroke-only" height=70 >
  <use href=#rects />
</svg>

<svg class="stroke-and-fill" height=70 >
  <use href=#rects />
</svg>
```

---

And then for the example in your codepen, you'll need to add specific rules for the one path that doesn't change color e.g:

```css
#mail path:not([class]) {
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: none;
}
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYPLwq).

But the best would be to mark it with a class (like I did with `.fixed`) if you have control over this sprite-sheet.

Comment: Nailed it! This best answers my original question.

Comment: I was able to simplify the CodePen a bit more and also add in another icon for testing. Here's where I ended up: https://codepen.io/amlyhamm/pen/yvqRyY

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what browsers you need to support - I would use CSS Variables
they take away all the hacks and pains of trying to control colors in SVGs and they works in the shadow DOM too.

1) Add the variables in your SVG as styles with a fallback for older browsers

```
<path style="fill: var(--color-name, #8d5000)" fill="#8d5000" d="M...." />
                   CSS variable      Default         Fallback
```

2)  Include your SVG

```
<svg class="my-class"><use xlink:href="#resource"></svg>
```

3)  Redefine the colors in your CSS

```
.my-class {
    --color-one: pink;
    --color-two: magenta;
}
```

4) That's it :-)

[Example on codepen](https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/ggGGRB)

[[image]

Support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: Yes good idea. If I may, a simpler example would probably better demonstrate the point made (which is good).

Answer (score 0):

There is only one "currentColor" so you can only change one thing that way.  However you can take advantage of the fact that elements can have a `stroke` and/or a `fill` to get two colour choices.  *(This is the logical extension of @Kaiido's example).*

Convert the strokes you want to be a different colour into filled shapes.  Leave the rest of the elements in stroked line form.  Now you can set some of the elements to one colour using `stroke`, and the rest using `fill`.

In thie following example, the top line is a `<line>`. We set its colour using the `stroke` attribute. The bottom line is actually a rectangle the same shape as the line. We set its colour using the `fill` attribute.

```css
body {
  color: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.example {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.example {
  stroke: green;
  fill: blue;
}

.single-color {
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0" id="__SVG_SPRITE_NODE__">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 64 64" id="mail">
    <!-- The top line is an actual line. -->
    <!-- We set its colour using the stroke attribute. -->
    <line x1="10" y1="20" x2="54" y2="20" stroke-width="16" fill="none"/>
    <!-- The bottom line is a path the same shape as the line -->
    <!-- We set its colour using the fill attribute. -->
    <path d="M 10,35 h44 v16 h-44 z"                        stroke="none" />
</symbol>
</svg>


<div class="example">
  <h2>Two Colors:</h2>

  <svg><use xlink:href="#mail"/></svg>
  
</div>

<div class="example">
  <h2>Single Color:</h2>

   <svg><use xlink:href="#mail" class="single-color"/></svg>
</div>
```

This approach will work for your example icon, and hopefully for the rest of your icons. But it will not work for every icon.  Obviously it relies on one of the colours being representable in stroke form.  If your icon was, say, two different coloured blobs, you may not be able to use this technique.