# How do you target objects nested within a <symbol> in an external sprite sheet?

Tags: css, svg

I'm using an external svg file for my graphics.  I have a few that are multi color and look something like this.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none;">

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 300 220" id="some_logo">
        <path id="shape01" d="...." />
        <path id="shape02" d="...." />
        <path id="shape03" d="...." />
    </symbol>

    <symbol>...</symbol>
    <symbol>...</symbol>
    <symbol>...</symbol>

</svg>
```

of course using it in the HTML looks like this.

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="../../assets/symbol_sprite.svg#some_logo" />
</svg>
```

The problem I'm having is I would like to target the `#shape01`, `#shape02` and `#shape03` ids to apply different css fills.  So far I tried

```
<use xlink:href="../../assets/symbol_sprite.svg#some_logo/#shape01" />
<use xlink:href="../../assets/symbol_sprite.svg#some_logo#shape01" />
<use xlink:href="../../assets/symbol_sprite.svg#some_logo>#shape01" />
```

just to see if I could find a way of targeting them but nothing happened.  I went to googling everything I could think of that might get a result but didn't get anything.  How can we target those elements?

Comment: [If you want to keep your SVG in (external) files, the CSS needs to be defined inside of the SVG file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720935/2908724)

Comment: If you want different fills - create different sprites.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940642/controlling-svg-colors-with-css/48943654#48943654 shows how you have to change your sprite file to leverage CSS variables for coloring different parts of a symbol. (Note that this works both for symbols defined inline and referenced form external files.)