# Reuse set of many objects but now assign each object a separate opacity, without copying all code?

Tags: css, svg

Let's imagine we have a large set of many objects, say rectangles. They all have opacity 1.

Now imagine that we want to copy all of those objects again to create a new set, but this time each object would need to be assigned a separate opacity.

One can create many such sets, and each time all of the individual objects would separately be assigned a certain opacity.

In cross-browser compatible SVG1.1 (optionally with SMIL/CSS), is there a way to do this, without needing to redraw all of the shapes and their alignments all over again (redrawing would make the code sort of long), for example using `set`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling SVG colors with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940642/controlling-svg-colors-with-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for goes like this:

```html
<svg width="300" height="150"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect id="template" x="20" y="20" width="80" height="80" />
  <use xlink:href="#template" x="100" style="opacity:0.6" fill="blue" />
  <use xlink:href="#template" x="200" style="opacity:0.3" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

The `<use>` elements reuse the template element. The `<rect>` is now in the so-called "shadow DOM" below that use element. While it is treated as if it was a child, it cannot be targeted by CSS style rules. But it can inherit styles (or presentation attributes) from the parent `<use>` element.

Note that the template element does not set an opacity. As a default, it is rendered with `opacity="1"`. Now if the `<use>` element sets another opacity, it can be applied to the cloned `<rect>` by inheritance.

If the template had an explicit  `opacity="1"`, the cloned `<rect>` would also get that. That style would have a higher specificity than the inherited one, and the rectangle would stay fully opaque.

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940642/controlling-svg-colors-with-css/48943654#48943654), if you want to clone sets of elements at once but give each of them individual opacity values, CSS variables can be leveraged. Note that presentation attributes no longer work. The most concise way to write this is a stylesheet that turns out to be a list of the property values to use.

```css
.stand {
    --red: 1;
    --amber: 0.3;
    --green: 0.3;
}
.wait {
    --red: 1;
    --amber: 1;
    --green: 0.3;
}
.go {
    --red: 0.3;
    --amber: 0.3;
    --green: 1;
}
.stop {
    --red: 0.3;
    --amber: 1;
    --green: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="200">
  <symbol id="trafficlight">
    <rect x="20" y="20"  width="60" height="160" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="#d00" style="opacity:var(--red, 1)" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="20" fill="#fa0" style="opacity:var(--amber, 1)" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="150" r="20" fill="#0b0" style="opacity:var(--green, 1)" />
  </symbol>
  <use x="0" xlink:href="#trafficlight" class="stand" />
  <use x="100" xlink:href="#trafficlight" class="wait" />
  <use x="200" xlink:href="#trafficlight" class="go" />
  <use x="300" xlink:href="#trafficlight" class="stop" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I am aware of your procedure, but it is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a shortcut. Please note that I am asking for multiple objects, not just one rectangle. They might be a set of 500 rectangles. The whole set needs to then be reproduced multiple times. Each rectangle in the set might need to be given an individual opacity, for every duplicate of the set. I might need to copy the whole set 10 times.

Comment: In this case I misunderstood your question. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940642/controlling-svg-colors-with-css/48943654#48943654) for a solution using CSS variables. Albeit for 500 different values that might get a bit messy, as you would have to define a varable for each of them...

Comment: I am looking more for something less character-intensive like <rect id="template" x="20" y="20" "IFin1=opacity:0.2341" "IFin2=opacity:0.2563463" "IFin3 ... et cetera. It would be nice if I could just refer to the whole group of objects to copy them, without needing to issue code to recall each individual rectangle.

Comment: @ccporog Coming back to the answer you had given, could you please tweak it so that the colour can also be changed?

Comment: Whether you use a style property or a presentation attribute is completly interchangable here. See edit. - Concerning the linked answer, it is not that much more verbose than your (hypothetical, but not working) approach. At some point you have to list the individual opacities/colors for each rectangle in each clone.

Comment: The problem with using `transform="scale(0.5 1)"` on some `<use` is that the position will also be altered (thus needing to restate the position as well, which is what we wanted to avoid to make the code less verbose in the first place).

Comment: I wonder if something similar is possible to tweak the SVG's `titles` as well? I have asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998972/svg1-1-is-it-possible-to-use-css-variables-to-change-the-the-title-descriptio