# Is it possible to use CSS variables to change the the TITLE (description on hover) contents of SVG objects?

Tags: svg, css-variables

Is it possible to use CSS variables (analogue to e.g. **opacity** in `style="opacity:var(--QQQ_SOMETHING_AAA, 1)"` and `.ZZZ_RECTANGLES{--QQQ_SOMETHING_AAA: 0.7;}` to tweak the SVGS's TITLE (description on hover `<title></title>`) contents?

I'm looking for something that will use only SVG1.1 features and SMIL/CSS, so no other plug-ins that might worsen cross-browser compatibility.

Here's a **MWE** code snippet:

```css
.HIDDEN_LAYER{
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
}
.CLICKME_TICKBOX{
  fill:white;
  stroke:black;
}
.CLICKED_TICKBOX{
  fill:white;
  stroke:black;
}
.CLICKME_TEXTS{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
}
.CLICKED_TEXTS{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  stroke:black;
  stroke-width:0.5;
}
.BOTTOM-LAYER_RECTANGLES{
  fill:white;
  stroke:black;
}
.ZZZ_RECTANGLES{
  visibility:hidden;
  cursor:help;
  fill:yellow;
  stroke:black;
  --QQQ_SOMETHING_AAA: 0.7;
  --QQQ_SOMETHING_BBB: 0.2;
}
.FFF_RECTANGLES{
  visibility:hidden;
  cursor:help;
  fill:red;
  stroke:black;
  --PPP_SOMETHING_AAA: 0.2;
  --PPP_SOMETHING_BBB: 0.7;
}
.LEGENDBOX_ZZZ{
  fill:yellow;
  stroke:black;
}
.LEGENDBOX_FFF{
  fill:red;
  stroke:black;
}
.LEGENDS{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg id="SVG"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="1320"
  height="1125"
  viewBox="-15 -45 1350 1155">

<symbol id="SOMETHING_AAA">
<use
  xlink:href="#RECTANGLE"
  transform="translate(637.5, 25)"
  style="
  opacity:var(--QQQ_SOMETHING_AAA, 1);
  fill-opacity:var(--PPP_SOMETHING_AAA, 1)
  ">
</use>
</symbol>
<symbol id="SOMETHING_BBB">
<use
  xlink:href="#RECTANGLE"
  transform="translate(15, 215)"
  style="
  opacity:var(--QQQ_SOMETHING_BBB, 1);
  fill-opacity:var(--PPP_SOMETHING_BBB, 1)
  ">
</use>
</symbol>

<g class="BOTTOM-LAYER_RECTANGLES">
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_AAA" />
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_BBB" />
</g>

<g class="ZZZ_RECTANGLES">
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_AAA">
<title>Something here 111.</title>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_BBB">
<title>Something here 222.</title>
</use>
<set
  to="visible"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="visibility"
  end="CLICKED_ZZZ.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_ZZZ.click" />
<set
  to="1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity"
  end="CLICKED_ZZZ.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_ZZZ.click" />
</g>

<g class="FFF_RECTANGLES">
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_AAA">
<title>Something here 333.</title>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_BBB">
<title>Something here 444.</title>
</use>
<set
  to="visible"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="visibility"
  end="CLICKED_DDD.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_DDD.click" />
<set
  to="1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity"
  end="CLICKED_DDD.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_DDD.click" />
</g>

<g id="LEGENDS"
  class="LEGENDS"
  transform="translate(15, -15)">

<g id="ZZZ">
<g id="CLICKME_ZZZ">
<rect id="CLICKME_TICKBOX_ZZZ"
  class="CLICKME_TICKBOX"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="15"
  height="15">
</rect>
<use id="CLICKME_LEGENDBOX_ZZZ"
  class="LEGENDBOX_ZZZ"
  x="30"
  y="-5"
  xlink:href="#LEGENDBOX">
</use>
<text id="CLICKME_TEXT_ZZZ"
  class="CLICKME_TEXTS"
  x="65"
  y="12.5">
Click me
</text>
</g>
<g id="CLICKED_ZZZ"
  class="HIDDEN_LAYER">
<use id="CLICKED_TICKBOX_ZZZ"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  xlink:href="#CLICKED_TICKBOX">
</use>
<use id="CLICKED_LEGENDBOX_ZZZ"
  class="LEGENDBOX_ZZZ"
  x="30"
  y="-5"
  xlink:href="#LEGENDBOX">
</use>
<text id="CLICKED_TEXT_ZZZ"
  class="CLICKED_TEXTS"
  x="65"
  y="12.5">
Click me
</text>
<set
  to="visible"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="visibility"
  end="CLICKED_ZZZ.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_ZZZ.click" />
<set
  to="1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity"
  end="CLICKED_ZZZ.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_ZZZ.click" />
</g>
<animate id="ZZZ_ANIMATE"
  fill="freeze"
  dur="3s"
  keyTimes="0;1"
  values="0;1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity" />
</g>

<g id="DDD"
   transform="translate(0,40)">
<g id="CLICKME_DDD">
<rect id="CLICKME_TICKBOX_FFF"
  class="CLICKME_TICKBOX"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="15"
  height="15">
</rect>
<use id="CLICKME_LEGENDBOX_FFF"
  class="LEGENDBOX_FFF"
  x="30"
  y="-5"
  xlink:href="#LEGENDBOX">
</use>
<text id="CLICKME_TEXT_FFF"
  class="CLICKME_TEXTS"
  x="65"
  y="12.5">
Click me
</text>
</g>
<g id="CLICKED_DDD"
  class="HIDDEN_LAYER">
<use id="CLICKED_TICKBOX_FFF"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  xlink:href="#CLICKED_TICKBOX">
</use>
<use id="CLICKED_LEGENDBOX_FFF"
  class="LEGENDBOX_FFF"
  x="30"
  y="-5"
  xlink:href="#LEGENDBOX">
</use>
<text id="CLICKED_TEXT_FFF"
  class="CLICKED_TEXTS"
  x="65"
  y="12.5">
Click me
</text>
<set
  to="visible"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="visibility"
  end="CLICKED_DDD.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_DDD.click" />
<set
  to="1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity"
  end="CLICKED_DDD.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_DDD.click" />
</g>
<animate id="DDD_ANIMATE"
  fill="freeze"
  dur="3s"
  keyTimes="0;1"
  values="0;1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity" />
</g>

</g>

<defs id="DEFINITIONS">
<rect id="RECTANGLE"
  width="85"
  height="95">
</rect>
<rect id="RECTANGLE_YELLOW"
  width="42.5"
  height="95">
</rect>
<rect id="LEGENDBOX"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="25"
  height="25">
</rect>
<path id="CLICKED_TICKBOX"
  class="CLICKED_TICKBOX"
  d="M 0,0 15,15 M 0,15 15,0 M 0,0 15,0 15,15 0,15 Z"/>
</defs>
```

It would be nice if the

```
<use
  xlink:href="#RECTANGLE"
  transform="translate(15, 215)"
  style="
  opacity:var(--QQQ_SOMETHING_BBB, 1);
  fill-opacity:var(--PPP_SOMETHING_BBB, 1)
  ">
</use>
```

Could also contain both of the titles:

```
<title>Something here 222.</title>
```

and

```
<title>Something here 444.</title>
```

depending on whether it is in `<g class="FFF_RECTANGLES">` or `<g class="ZZZ_RECTANGLES">`.

So, it would be nice if the code could be altered, for example as:

```
<use
  xlink:href="#RECTANGLE"
  transform="translate(15, 215)"
  style="
  opacity:var(--QQQ_SOMETHING_BBB, 1);
  fill-opacity:var(--PPP_SOMETHING_BBB, 1)"
  title=:var(--SSS_SOMETHING, Or else it will be this.);
  var(--TTT_SOMETHING, Or else it will be that.)"
  ">
</use>
```

The title could then be stated in:

```
.ZZZ_RECTANGLES{
  --QQQ_SOMETHING_AAA: 0.7;
  --QQQ_SOMETHING_BBB: 0.2;
  --SSS_SOMETHING: Something here 222.;
}
```

and

```
.FFF_RECTANGLES{
  --PPP_SOMETHING_AAA: 0.2;
  --PPP_SOMETHING_BBB: 0.7;
  --TTT_SOMETHING: Something here 444.;
}
```

Comment: Questions asking "Is there a way to do X?" / "Can I do X?" / "Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, the question is usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you want. Right now, this is a "yes"/"no" question. Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have (minimal, but complete) example SVG code and how it's contained in your HTML that actually shows what you're trying to have changed? Are you asking for arbitrary changes to the text shows? Or, to select from a subset which is already contained in the SVG? Or, are you wanting the possible titles to be contained in the CSS? Does it need to be the SVG's `<title></title>`, or just something that appears *like* a tooltip? Could it be a tooltip that's on the element containing the SVG? Basically, there's a lot of area here that you need to define for us.

Comment: Is the SVG which you want to affect fully within your control, or is it something that you can't change? Stated in a different way, can we make the SVG to be arbitrarily whatever we desire/need in order to make something work (I assume so, because you've given no example SVG)?

Comment: @Makyen Thank you, I have made a MWE now and added more info, please delete your comments above if no longer applicable.

Comment: The SVG title attribute is not reflected in CSS, is it? I wouldn't imagine that you could do this directly if that were the case.

Answer (score 1):

Titles in SVG are elements, not attributes.  So I don't believe there is any feaible way to achieve what you want using only CSS.

Since JS is universally supported, I assume you wouldn't have objection to using that to achieve this?

```js
// Take the text typed into the input box, and use it for the tootip for the red rectangle
document.getElementById("title-input").addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
  setTitleText("rect-title", this.value);
});

function setTitleText(elementId, newText) {
  document.getElementById(elementId).textContent = newText;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect y="50" width="200" height="50" fill="red">
    <title id="rect-title">Default title</title>
  </rect>
</svg>

<p>Enter some text to use as a title tooltip for the rect</p>
<input type="text" id="title-input"/>
```

Comment: I can't permit using JS, I'm sorry. The purpose is to upload the files to Wikimedia Commons. JS is not supported.