# SVG defs multiple elements CSS change one

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have an SVG element in an HTML page. Elements change classes through Javascript so, for example, I can programmatically change traffic light graphics from green to red. This works fine for simple elements but I'm struggling when the SVG template (in a `defs` section, instantiated with `use`) that contains more than one graphic type (`rect`, `ellipse` etc) where the class change should only affect some but not all graphics.

SVG:

```
<defs>
  <g id="pointUL">
    <rect x="0" y="4" width="8" height="4"  ---element1--- />
    <polygon points="2,0 6,0 8,4 8,8" ---element2--- />
  </g>
</defs>
<use id="ICX_P647YA" xlink:href="#pointUL" x="184" y="128" />
```

Javascript:

```
function updateItem(item) {
    var element = document.getElementById(item.title);
    if (element != null) {
            element.className.baseVal = item.cssClass;
```

CSS:

```
.trackPointOccOOC {
  fill: red;
}
```

So the above snippets work where I want both the rect and the polygon to turn red when I call updateItem with item.cssClass = trackPointOOC.

But the effect I need is that the rect and the polygon are in three states: that is, the rect is displayed, or the polygon is displayed, or both are displayed (or they gain different colours, or whatever). Again, I can show/hide all the elements of pointUL, but I need each element to be individually gain their own characteristics. While I've used a rect and a polygon, there could be 5 rects and an ellipse, or a rect+ellipse+polygon, or whatever.

If it is possible then I guess the CSS and the SVG need to be linked together through ---element1--- and ---element2--- so the CSS would have subsections:

```
.trackPointOccOOC {
  ---element1---
  fill: red;
  ---element2---
  fill: black;
}
```

Maybe this is not possible and I have to think of another way. Or maybe it's stupidly obvious :) I'm not good at CSS. Thanks.

[Edit] ccprog's link certainly pointed me in the right direction (thanks) but I think it's worthy of a full answer (below).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reuse set of many objects but now assign each object a separate opacity, without copying all code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980640/reuse-set-of-many-objects-but-now-assign-each-object-a-separate-opacity-without)

Comment: Definitely pointed me in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS contains a number of variables which control the element:

```
.trackPointOccOOC {
  --colourN: red;
  --visibleN: block;
  --colourR: red;
  --visibleR: block;
  animation: redFlash 1s infinite;
}
.trackPointLockN {
  --colourN: white;
  --visibleN: block;
  --colourR: grey;
  --visibleR: none;
  animation: none;
}
.trackPointLockR {
  --colourN: grey;
  --visibleN: none;
  --colourR: white;
  --visibleR: block;
  animation: none;
}
```

(there are 9 states, 3 shown above)

Then the SVG defs:

```
<g id="pointUL">
  <rect x="0" y="4" width="8" height="4" style="fill: var(--colourN); display: var(--visibleN);" />
  <polygon points="2,0 6,0 8,4 8,8" style="fill: var(--colourR); display: var(--visibleR);" />
</g>
```

Finally the SVG is unchanged:

```
<use id="ICX_P647YA" xlink:href="#pointUL" x="184" y="128" />
```

The Javascript is also unchanged.