# How do I properly target SVG symbol paths on hover?

Tags: css, svg

I can't seem to properly target a symbol's path stroke when hovering.

There's a similar entry but it doesn't seem to target hovering. (  [Controlling SVG colors with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940642/controlling-svg-colors-with-css) )

In trying just to change the stroke on the use tag it just 'adds' a stroke where there wasn't one before

```
 .terminal:hover {cursor:pointer;stroke:#000;}
```

When trying to target the path's themselves, it doesn't work at all

```
 .terminal:hover path {stroke:#000;}
```

Does the Symbol change things for CSS targeting?

https://codepen.io/trevcis/pen/OYMLqO

Comment: The ability to style USED content with CSS is very limited. I'm surprised it works at all. https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling SVG colors with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940642/controlling-svg-colors-with-css)

Comment: @MichaelMullany it works on the one element that doesn't have any `stroke` rule set.

Comment: I would think symbols would be such a common thing that the hovers would work.  both links  are interesting reads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Replace `.terminal:hover path {stroke:#000;}` with `.terminal:hover use {stroke:#000;}` as the actual node inside of `.terminal` is `use`, not `path`. It works on Chrome, FF, and Safari. Not sure about IE.</s>

---

Updated answer:

If you want to use one same symbol but want to change each one's stroke color based on hover, you can try with **CSS variables**. Try below:

```css
.terminal {
  --color-st0: #f00; /* #54565A */
  --color-st1: #0f0; /* #E2ECF5 */
}

.terminal:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.terminal:hover use {
  --color-st0: #333333;
  --color-st1: #333333;
}

.st0TERMINAL{
  fill:none;
  stroke: var(--color-st0);
  stroke-width:6;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
}

.st1TERMINAL{
  fill:none;
  stroke: var(--color-st1);
  stroke-width:2;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
}

.st2TERMINAL{
  fill:#789904;
}
```

```html
<svg id="assets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-6 -6 200 200">
  <symbol  id="terminal" viewBox="0 0 16.8 16.8">
    <path class="st0TERMINAL" d="M-0.8,2.6c0,0-1.8,0-1.8-1.8v-1.6c0,0,0-1.8,1.8-1.8h1.6c0,0,1.8,0,1.8,1.8v1.6c0,0,0,1.8-1.8,1.8H-0.8z"/>
    <path class="st1TERMINAL" d="M-0.8,2.6c0,0-1.8,0-1.8-1.8v-1.6c0,0,0-1.8,1.8-1.8h1.6c0,0,1.8,0,1.8,1.8v1.6c0,0,0,1.8-1.8,1.8H-0.8z"/>
    <path class="st2TERMINAL" d="M-0.8,2.6c0,0-1.8,0-1.8-1.8v-1.6c0,0,0-1.8,1.8-1.8h1.6c0,0,1.8,0,1.8,1.8v1.6c0,0,0,1.8-1.8,1.8H-0.8z"/>
  </symbol>
  <g id="terminal1" class="terminal">
    <use xlink:href="#terminal"  width="12" height="12" x="0" y="0" style="overflow:visible;"/>
  </g>  
  <g id="terminal2" class="terminal">
    <use xlink:href="#terminal"  width="12" height="12" x="5" y="5" style="overflow:visible;"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I updated the pen and it appears to work the same?  
https://codepen.io/trevcis/pen/OYMLqO

Comment: @user2979402 Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. Check my updated answer. Hopefully I got you correctly this time!! ;)

Comment: @user2979402 awesome, happy to be able to help! Actually it was a good question that I have never thought about. Good luck!